# Javascript getting DOM children as a String

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML document with the following code

```
    <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="label">First Name : </div>
<div class="value">John Doe</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using javascript I want to access the contents of div#wrapper as a string like

```
var s = '<div class="label">First Name : </div><div class="value">John Doe</div>';
```

tried

```
var wrapperContent = document.getElementBydId("wrapper").innerHTML; // returns First Name : John Doe
```

but this gives me only the text values. Anyways I can achieve this ??

Comment: some newlines in the html code would be nice :P

Comment: `innerHTML` should work; for example, try `document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML` on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted should work.

I believe your problem is that you are trying to get the innerHTML of an element that does not have a parent yet.

Comment: false. His problem is that he mistyped ` getElementById `

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` should work fine.  For example, try `document.getElementBydId("wrapper").innerHTML` on this page.

Be sure you're executing the Javascript at either the end of the document, or within some incarnation of the `window.onload` event.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's method

```
$('#wrapper').html
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you type `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementBydId` =)

You just mistyped..

**EDIT**: Look here, it works! http://www.jsfiddle.net/rVa9t/